# if $f(0)=1$ and f is analytic, there can't be $f(z_0)=0$ with $|z_0|<M$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let be $f$ analytic  in the disc with radius $$1 from the beginning, and continuous on the boundary of the disc. let $f(0)=1$ and also let $z$ on the boundary satisfies $1<|f(z)|<M$.
Then there can't be $|z_{0}|<\frac{1}{M}$ satisfying  $f(z_0)=0$ .
I thought about using Cauchy integral formula but it doesn't seem to be useful.

Edit: I thought about that idea: $M$ is the maximum value on the disc. So for every sub disc the maximum value must be $M$. Let be $z_0$ a zero on the sub-disc, then there is an environment that is smaller than $1$. Therefore the integral on the sub disc must be less than $1$, which contradicts the value in the center of the disc.

Comment: Can you update your question using $\vert \cdot \vert$ when required? For example $z_0 < \frac{1}{M}$ is not well defined for complex numbers. Thanks.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net done

Comment: Do you have $|f(z)| < M$ for *all* $z$ on the boundary of the unit disk or for *some* $z$?

Comment: it is known that the entire boundary of the disc is bounded by M. (by absolute value)

Comment: That's what I assumed, but your question is a bit unclear in that respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|f|$ is bounded by $M$ in the unit disk then $g(z) = f(z)/M$ maps the unit disk into itself.

Now let $z_0$ be a zero of $f$ in the unit disk. Then $g(0) = 1/M$ and $g(z_0) = 0$ and the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) shows that
$$
\frac 1M = |g(0)| = \left|{\frac  {g(0)-g(z_{0})}{1-\overline {g(0)}g(z_{0})}}\right|\leq \left|{\frac  {0-z_0}{1-\overline {0}z_0}}\right| = |z_0| \, .
$$
So every zero $z_0$ of $f$ in the unit disk satisfies $|z_0| \ge 1/M$.

Comment: interesting is my solution seems to be right?

Comment: @hashman: I don't think it works, to be honest. For a starter, why should the maximum of $f$ on any subdisk be $M$?

Comment: because holomorphic function gets its maximun on the boundary, which is bounded by M.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle

Comment: @hashman: $f(z) = 1+z$ is bounded by $2$ on the unit disk. That does not mean that the maximum of $|f|$ is equal to $2$ on every subdisk.

Comment: nope, but it is bounded by 2.

Comment: @hashman: I am fairly sure that Schwarz-Pick (which is just a variant of the famous Schwarz Lemma) is the correct way to go. If you elaborate on your attempt in your question then we can better judge if it works or not.