# Zeros of bounded analytic functions on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I encountered this in the sample qual exams for complex analysis. Here is the question: 
Let $f$ be an analytic function on the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ with $|f(z)|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ on $\mathbb{D}$ and $f(0)=r\in\mathbb{R}$. Here $0<r<\frac{1}{2}$.

(a) Prove that $f(z)$ has no zeros in the disc $\{|z|<2r\}$.

(b) Can $f(z)$ have a zero on the circle $\{|z|=2r\}$? If so, find all such functions $f(z)$. 
I was stuck with (a). I think Schwartz lemma might work. Let $g(z)=f(z)-r$, then $g(0)=0$ and $|g(z)|\leq \frac{1}{2}+r$ so apply Schwartz lemma we will get $|g(z)|\leq(\frac{1}{2}+r)|z|$. Therefore, $|g(z)|<r$ when $|z|<\frac{r}{1/2+r}$, which implies $f(z)$ is never zero when $|z|<\frac{r}{1/2+r}$. This is not good enough since $2r>\frac{r}{1/2+r}$. Is it possible to modify this proof so that it works well or it can be shown in some other way?

Comment: Hint: apply a conformal transform to $f$.

Comment: The name is "Schwarz” – not “Schwartz” and not “Schwart” :)

Comment: schwarz-pick is what works

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3991908/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I didn't know the theorem when I did the problem but that's a short and elegant proof.